# Unexpected scaling of UI elements after build [Unity Web]

Tags: unity, gui, webgl

I have an unusual scaling of UI Elements after my build in unity for WebGL

Game in Unity Engine:
[image]

Game in Itch.io:

[image]

Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour? any suggestions on what I should look into? 
Happy to provide more info on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: How have you configured your UI Canvas object in the Inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your Canvas scaling properties. By default the Canvas that you use doesn't scale with the resolution. So if you work in Unity with a small resolution (your game window size defines the resolution you're using, in your case it's a 4:3 ratio resolution but it seems very small), let's say 640x480 and try to play the game after building it on a 1280x1024 screen resolution, your canvas will still be 640x480 and at the middle of the screen.

To avoid that behaviour you can add a component `CanvasScaler` on your Canvas and define the behaviour you're expecting (I feel like you want a "Match width or height" mode). [You can find more about the Canvas Scaler here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html).

Comment: (and welcome here Arman!)

Comment: Ah Thanks so much! It was previously set to constant pixel size. I'll get back to you on how it goes.

Comment: And thanks for the welcome! @Ivictorino

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. Marking as correct @lvictorino